# It is not possible to use the google maps API with Angular 2 (http.get)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, angular

I need some guidance in this matter. I am using Angular2 and I just want to use the google maps API (distance Matrix API) to calculate the distance between two points.

I tested first the link at the browser (sorry the google Maps API Key is not attached):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=ABADI%C3%91O&destinations=Barcelona&key=YourGoogleMapsAPIKey

This link works without problems, I receive the following:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Barcelona, Barcelona, España" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "48220 Abadiño, Vizcaya, España" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "617 km",
                  "value" : 617099
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5h 42 min",
                  "value" : 20512
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status"
```

So far so good. Well, I thought this was pretty straightforward with Angular2, just using the http.get and then converting the answer from json. Well, either I made a silly mistake that I am not able to find or it is not so easy. I allways get the following error from Angular 2 when I send the corresponding request to the Google Maps API:

```
BrowserDomAdapter</BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.logError() angular2.dev.js:25644
BrowserDomAdapter</BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.logGroup() angular2.dev.js:25655
ExceptionHandler</ExceptionHandler.prototype.call() angular2.dev.js:4863
ApplicationRef_/<() angular2.dev.js:8167
EventEmitter</EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<() angular2.dev.js:7865
SafeSubscriber</SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub() rx.js:10775
SafeSubscriber</SafeSubscriber.prototype.next() rx.js:10730
Subscriber</Subscriber.prototype._next() rx.js:10690
Subscriber</Subscriber.prototype.next() rx.js:10667
Subject</Subject.prototype._finalNext() rx.js:11191
Subject</Subject.prototype._next() rx.js:11183
Subject</Subject.prototype.next() rx.js:11142
EventEmitter</EventEmitter.prototype.emit() angular2.dev.js:7846
NgZone/this._zoneImpl<.onError() angular2.dev.js:8359
NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onHandleError() angular2.dev.js:2206
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.handleError() angular2-polyfills.js:353
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask() angular2-polyfills.js:285
ZoneTask/this.invoke()
```

The function I am using is:

```
  getResponse(url: string) {

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept-Encoding','gzip');

        var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            url: url,
            headers: headers
        });

        return this.http.get(url)
            .do(data => this._logger.debug(data, "Get -> Raw reponse: "))
            .map(res => <Event[]>res.json())
            .do(data => this._logger.debug(data, "Get -> After json parsing: "))  // eyeball results in the console
            .catch(this._logger.handleResponseError);

    }
```

And now my questions:

- Could you give me any advice?
- Does anybody from you have an idea of what could happen? I tried to use an XMLHttpRequest, however, Angular2 does not seem to "like it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to execute a web service request via AJAX and apparently have an issue related to same-origin policy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

The Distance Matrix API does not include CORS headers in the response, so you are unable to retrieve the data via AJAX request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Solution: use a Maps JavaScript API distance matrix service instead of the web service request via AJAX.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

Comment: Thank you very much for the help xomena